# Play video file on splash screen

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen

Can I play a video file in the splash screen?

I use `Defualt.png` and sleep interval method to use static splash screen. Instead of an image, I want to play a video of about 10 sec.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the default image is shown by the system while your app is loading, so your code isn't running yet (kinda the whole point).  Once it is loaded, you can create a media player and play your video.

Comment: so, that means, maximum things in splash screen is done through animation only. like NFS.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. The loading splash screen is a static png. You can only play a video once your app starts.

Comment: if i want to give animation at splash screen, than how to do it? dat wat i was asking.?

Comment: See above - you cannot animate the splash screen shown by the system while your app is loading. When the user selects your app from the home screen, the system reads your app's Info.plist, reads the Default.png image and displays that while it loads the app binary. This is a static image. Once loading the binary is finished, your app runs and after init, application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: gets called. At this point you can do whatever you like, including play a video or animation.

Answer (score 4):

Just make Default.png to be the first frame of your video. When the application is loaded, start the video. This is something in between. Hope it helps.